# How to correctly parse Object object in Angular2?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm trying to iterate through a json object that has the following structure.

[image]

Based on suggestions found on stackoverflow, I've added a pipe for processing this kind of objects.

```
@Pipe({name: 'keysPipe'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```

And then I'm attempting to utilize ***ngFor** directive like the following:

```
<span *ngFor="let entry of permissions | keysPipe">
  {{entry.key}} {{entry.value}}
</span>
```

And what I get is this

[image]

How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it like this:

```
<span *ngFor="let permission of permissions.permissions">
  {{permission.id}} {{permission.email}}
</span>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/wPDIAdXmlCYmTDwB15Ok?p=preview)**

[image]